# ArcGIS Vehicle Routing Problem Service via REST

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-rest-api

I am trying to get a Vehicle Routing Problem to work as a geoprocessing service on one of our servers.

I used the default_date with unix time stamp in miliseconds and set the times of orders and depot in the format of "10:00 AM UTC". Now I get a time constraint violation for the orders ("ViolatedConstraints": 32)

If I take out the line "MaxViolationTime1":0 from the orders in my REST url, a route is calculated with correct travel times and distances and I can see the results. Especially the following lines (attributes of output route) caught my eye:

```
...
"TotalCost": 42.5174562651664,
"RegularTimeCost": 42.5174562651664,
...
"TotalTime": 42.5174562651664,
"TotalOrderServiceTime": 20,
...
"TotalTravelTime": 22.517456265166402,
...
"StartTime": 1369180800000,
"EndTime": 1369183351047,
...
"TotalViolationTime": 30.35018770210445,
...
```

I can change the default date and the earliest/latest start time, but the route starts still on the current date, at 2 AM. Could it be that some date and time options are "hard coded" somewhere in the module that was used to create the geoprocessing service? I checked the module again and can't find any options to change default date and time settings.

Answer (score 1):

```
default_date
```

> The parameter value should be specified as a numeric value
>   representing the milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970.

Default is in minutes:

> Use this parameter to specify the time units for all time-based
>   attribute values specified with different parameters. The parameter is
>   specified using one of the following values: Seconds, Minutes, Hours,
>   Days.
>
> Many parameters in the vehicle routing problem request have attributes
>   for storing time values, such as ServiceTime for the orders parameter
>   and CostPerUnitTime for the routes parameter. To minimize data entry
>   requirements, these attribute values don't include units. Instead, all
>   time-based attribute values must be entered in the same units, and the
>   time_units parameter is used to specify the units of those values.

Example request:

```
https://logistics.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/VehicleRoutingProblem/GPServer/SolveVehicleRoutingProblem/submitJob?token=yourToken&orders={"features":[{"geometry":{"x":-122.51,"y":37.7724},"attributes":{"DeliveryQuantities":1706,"Name":"Store_1","ServiceTime":25,"TimeWindowStart1":1355245200000,"TimeWindowEnd1":1355274000000,"MaxViolationTime1":0}},{"geometry":{"x":-122.4889,"y":37.7538},"attributes":{"DeliveryQuantities":1533,"Name":"Store_2","ServiceTime":23,"TimeWindowStart1":1355245200000,"TimeWindowEnd1":1355274000000,"MaxViolationTime1":0}},{"geometry":{"x":-122.4649,"y":37.7747},"attributes":{"DeliveryQuantities":1580,"Name":"Store_3","ServiceTime":24,"TimeWindowStart1":1355245200000,"TimeWindowEnd1":1355274000000,"MaxViolationTime1":0}},{"geometry":{"x":-122.4739,"y":37.7432},"attributes":{"DeliveryQuantities":1289,"Name":"Store_4","ServiceTime":20,"TimeWindowStart1":1355245200000,"TimeWindowEnd1":1355274000000,"MaxViolationTime1":0}},{"geometry":{"x":-122.4493,"y":37.7315},"attributes":{"DeliveryQuantities":1302,"Name":"Store_5","ServiceTime":21,"TimeWindowStart1":1355245200000,"TimeWindowEnd1":1355274000000,"MaxViolationTime1":0}},{"geometry":{"x":-122.4917,"y":37.6493},"attributes":
```

**Full documentation: (ArcGIS 10.2 preview)**

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#//02r3000000n4000000

Comment: The time units are actually already correct. If I add "time_units=Minutes", nothing in the outuput changes. The "StartTime" date still differs from the default_date.